# Divergence theorem and flux.

Tags: calculus

[image]

I just decided that i would separate it in three surface, one with z=0, one with z=3 (ellipses) and the one we want to calculate. And so i would apply the divergence theorem, but that is confusing me. Anyway, i will throw the z=0 and z=3 integral away because the normal is orthogonal to F there.

See: $\int \int \vec{F} \vec{dS} = ? \int \int \int divF dv$

I am having some doubts about this equality. the first problem is about the surface $(9x^2+4y^2−1) = 0$. Of course this will disturb something in the equalitty above, since F diverges there. Generally i am accostumed to use a sphere around the singularity, being the singularity a point and not a whole surface. So i tried to consider the equalitty now:

$\int \int  \vec{F} \vec{dS} - \int \int _{9x^2+4y^2−1 = 0} \vec{F} \vec{dS}= \int \int \int divF dv$

I am definitelly confused because i am not sure if this singularity is a type o cyinder with the cross sec being the elipse. Or if it is two plane ellipses, one in z=0 and other at z=3.

Anyway, i calculated like this: $\int\int (4y/(9x^2+4y^2−1),−9x/(9x^2+4y^2−1))*(18x,4y,0)dxdy$, where $(18x,4y,0) = \nabla (9x^2+4y^2-1)$.
$$\int\int (4y/(9x^2+4y^2−1),−9x/(9x^2+4y^2−1))*(18x,4y,0)dxdy = \int \int 0 dxdy = 0$$ So i got zero. SInce the div is also zero, the flux $\int \int Fds$ is zero...

I am not sure if this is right because of the confusion above....

Comment: @RobertLee OP closed their surface with two planes since the flux across both is $0$

Answer (score 2):

There is a slightly easier trick to use than divergence theorem. Notice that your surface has symmetry about the $x=0$ and $y=0$ planes and that the $i$ component is an odd function of $y$ and the $j$ component is an odd function of $x$. Therefore the flux is $0$ by odd function symmetry.

Comment: Oh that's true. Thank you, i will use it in another exercises. But the way i solved here, is it right? (the way that i dealt with the singulairty being a hole surface))

Comment: .m @Ninad Munshi